# Removing lag without restarting Android

Tags: android-10, oxygenos

I'm using OP6T Oxygen OS (Android 10).

After scrolling through lot of data, the phone becomes a bit laggy. Restarting fixes it. Is there a quick fix without restarting?'

Any tips?

Comment: Does this lag occur independently of the apps you use for "scrolling lot of data"? Have you tried killing the used app or all apps? Are all apps affected by this lag or only the one you used for scrolling?

Comment: If this is a system wide problem than OnePlus has to issue a patch. You would have to ask/complaint on their forums though. Pretty much nothing (short of trying a different kernel maybe) you can do to fix this.

Comment: @Robert I think it can be due to cpu temperature rise perhaps because it happens in all apps though after a long time of rapid continuous scrolling for eg. twitter and likes. I'll try this next time to let the phone rest and check. Will update the findings